# Permission Denied in GitLab project deploy

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to setup GitLab on my aws server.

what I am trying to do-

1. **Push the branch from local system to GitLab server.**
2. **merge the branch on GitLab server and deploy to staging server using SSH.**
3. **If Everything fine deploy to production server using SSH.**
4. **Revert the changes on staging or production server.**

What I have done so far-

- Setup the GitLab on server.
- Can push the branch from local server and can merge on GitLab.

**Problem:**

Problem I am facing in deploying the branch are-

Unable to deploy the branch on staging server.

[image]

```
    stages:
      - staging

    deploy_staging:
      stage: staging
      before_script:
        - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      script:
        - ssh user@ip "cd /home/public_html/gitlab-test &&
            git checkout master &&
            git pull origin master "
      environment: staging
      only:
        - master
```

I followed

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html

https://www.sebastianklier.com/gitlab/2017/10/01/automatic-deployments-to-remote-with-gitlab-ci.html

https://florianbrinkmann.com/en/3473/deployment-gitlab-ci/

https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-ci-cd-on-gitlab-step-by-step-guide-part-1-826385728223

But look like I am missing something. Any video tutorial or detailed explanation will be really appreciated.

I am not using Docker in this.

Comment: Can you ssh into server? It looks like you don't have proper authorization. Maybe your password or your ssh-keys are wrong.

Comment: Yes, i can ssh into remote server from Gitlab server using password.

Comment: I never tried to connect GitLab like this, but I'm thinking that this script will try to connect using ssh keys. You can try to temporary change this script to use password (if it'll work then you'll know it's authentication problem). Then you should verify that you AWS has properly set access via ssh-keys (server allows that and your public ssh-key is set on AWS machine to allow access).